# How to update a dictionary every N seconds and return the difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, dictionary, python-requests

I am making a GET request to an API that gives me a dictionary of songs. **My goal is too keep up with the new releases by making this same GET request every N seconds and then printing the difference between the latest request and the current request every N seconds if there is one.**

For example, my first GET request returns `{'SongA': '11/09/2019', 'SongB': ''11/10/2019'}`. The next GET request (in N seconds) returns `{'SongA': '11/09/2019', 'SongB': '11/10/2019', 'SongC': '11/11/2019'}` and so I want to `print` `{'SongC': '11/11/2019'}`.

**In other words, the dictionary returned in the prior GET request needs to be overwritten every N seconds with the latest dictionary returned from the current request.**

I am unsure how to use `threading` correctly here.

I am using the `requests` library.

Comment: Remove the common keys in the latest request. current = {'SongA': '11/09/2019', 'SongB': '11/10/2019'}
latest = {'SongA': '11/09/2019', 'SongB': '11/10/2019', 'SongC': '11/11/2019'}
for key in current:
    latest.pop(key, None)

Comment: @SebinSunny but how can I do this every N seconds?

Comment: `import time, threading
def n_seconds():
   print(time.ctime())
    threading.Timer(0.5, n_seconds).start()

n_seconds()` The function is executed periodically in every 0.5s. please provide similar API then I can help you with python request